# Fluent Validation seems to stop after the first failure

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I've been updating my fluent Validations from 10 to 11 but I've suddenly got a lot of unit test errors that push me toward believing that Fluent Validations is not executing all of the rules.  This seems against all the documentation and I'm not finding anyone else complaining about it so I'm confused.

I have a test that looks for several null values, and should return a failure for each, however it only returns the first failure, swapping the rule order makes the error return differently.

Any tips are appreciated.

```
public sealed class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>

    {
        public Validator()
        {
            //ClassLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;
            RuleFor(x => x.Id).ValidateId();
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).ValidateAccountName();
            RuleFor(x => x.Description).ValidateAccountDescription();
            RuleFor(x => x.Status).ValidateAccountStatus();
            When(
                x => !(x.prop1is null) || !(x.prop2 is null) || !(x.prop 3 is null),
                () =>
                {
                    RuleFor(x => x.prop1Enum).NotNull().IsInEnum();
                    RuleFor(x => x.prop2Number).ValidateNumber();
                    RuleFor(x => x.prop3Number).ValidateNumber(); 
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Test

```
public void Validator_ShouldReturnErrors_WhenAccountInfoIsPartiallyProvided(
        bool excludeProp1,
        bool excludeProp2,
        bool excludeProp3,
        UpdateAccount.Validator sut,
        IFixture fixture
    )
    {
        // arrange
        var command = BuildValidCommand(fixture, excludeProp1, excludeProp2, excludeprop3)
            .Create();

        // act
        var result = sut.Validate(command);

        // assert
        using var _ = new AssertionScope();
        result.Errors.Should().HaveCountLessOrEqualTo(3);

        if (excludeprop1)
        {
            result.Errors.Should()
                .Contain(
                    f => f.PropertyName == nameof(UpdateAccount.Command.prop1) &&
                        f.ErrorMessage.Contains("must not be empty")
                );
        }

        if (excludeProp2)
        {
            result.Errors.Should()
                .Contain(
                    f => f.PropertyName == nameof(UpdateAccount.Command.Prop2) &&
                        f.ErrorMessage.Contains("must not be empty")
                );
        }

        if (excludeProp3)
        {
            result.Errors.Should()
                .Contain(
                    f => f.PropertyName == nameof(UpdateAccount.Command.Prop3) &&
                        f.ErrorMessage.Contains("must not be empty")
                );
        }
    }
```

Comment: @daniherrera: you can type `[mre]` in comments to get a nice link without much typing: [mre]

Comment: Can you post a [mwe](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? cc / @ThomasWeller

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the data generators for my tests was putting the validators in this bad state.  I have fixed them all by putting them into the proper state.